# Can I generate CREATE TABLE from a visio diagram?

Tags: database, visio

I have a database diagram done up in Visio 2003 Professional.

Is there any way to re-engineer the database from the diagram?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need Visio for Enterprise Architects, which was previously supplied with some of the higher editions of Visual Studio. It (and only it) had the ability to generated database scripts from a Visio diagram.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, older versions of Visio could do it in the standard version. Visio 2000 (yes, that old) had very solid forward and reverse engineering functionality. Maybe you can get hold of that version (current versions should still be able to save in that format).